# Determining styles for a html node

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium, html-agility-pack

I have many html files generated with MS Word. The html code is mostly tables with text nodes, paragraphs, spans, etc. The files don't contain javascript or exhibit any other dynamic behavior. But what they do have are CSS styles.

Is there a way with htmlagilitypack to determine the style for a html node when it's declared in the CSS section? As far as I understand it htmlagilitypack doesn't parse CSS when the DOM is created. Correct?

If htmlagilitypack cannot resolve CSS styles what are the best tools to do it? Should I use Selenium instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium has the answer via Javascript.

```
ChromeOptions Options = new ChromeOptions();
Options.AddArgument("--headless");
IWebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver(Options);
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"file://Some_File.html");

// The correct style
var properties = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],null).cssText", e);

Driver.Close();
Driver.Quit();
```